# How to convert string into valid date format if I provide month and days as optional

Tags: java, date, java-time

I want to convert my string into valid date format even months and days are optional

For Example, I have the following string like below

```
String date1 = "20-12-2021"
String date2 = "12-2021" i.e without day
String date3 = "2021" i.e without day & month
String date4 = "21" i.e without day, month & just last two digits of the year
```

I want to convert all the above strings format into the valid date with 'yyyy-mm-dd' format as below,

```
For date1, Date should be "2021-12-20" 
For date2, Date should be "2021-12-01"
For date3, Date should be "2021-01-01" 
For date4, Date should be "2021-01-01"
```

Could you please help me with this? Any info will be really helpful. I can't define single string formatted for parser since the string format is unpredictable in my scenario.

Comment: If your input is only "21" how do you know which century, month and day you need to add?

Comment: If my input is only '21' then I should make the default year as 20th century. And If I didn't supply month and day, then my month and day should always point to 01 & 01. Hope this info is clear!!

Comment: @saravanakumar I guess you meant 21st century (from 2001 to 2100)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yes, Typo error. I was actually intended to mention 21century. I will update in my comment

Comment: @saravanakumar I'm afraid it's too late. Better to delete it an re-write it. Then when you're done flag my comments as "no longer needed" so they will be deleted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) with multiple patterns and default values of missing parts (month and day):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("[dd-MM-uuuu]")
        .appendPattern("[MM-uuuu]")
        .appendPattern("[uuuu]")
        .appendPattern("[uu]")
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
        .toFormatter();
```

**Outputs**

```
2021-12-20
2021-12-01
2021-01-01
2021-01-01
```

Answer (score 2):

A whacky yet working solution in your special case would be the following:

```java
public class DateParser {
  private static String defaultDate = "01-01-2000";
  private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
  
  public static LocalDate parseDate(String date) {
    String fullDate = defaultDate.substring(0, defaultDate.length() - date.length()) + date;
    return LocalDate.parse(fullDate, formatter);
  }

}
```

Basically, use a default full date, e.g. `01-01-2000`, and then combine it with the input date. Then, use the formatter `dd-MM-yyyy` to parse the date. One of the advantages is that it reuses the same formatter, hence is very efficient. However, you may need to add some checks and exception handling.

To test it:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List.of(
      "20-12-2021",
      "12-2021",
      "2021",
      "21"
  ).forEach(date -> System.out.println(parseDate(date)));
}
```

Output:

```
2021-12-20
2021-12-01
2021-01-01
2021-01-01
```

(I must admit @YCF_L solution is more elegant though)